# Send Image over AWS SNS Notification with Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, base64, boto3, amazon-sns

I am trying to send an image stored in AWS Lambda /tmp/ folder.

I extract the image from AWS Kinesis Video Stream and write them to /tmp/ using opencv.

I am testing the code locally using boto3 but this would normally be in a lambda function.

```
import boto3
import base64


if __name__ == '__main__':

    client = boto3.client('sns')
    phone_number = '+12345678900'
    
    img = open('tmp/image10.jpeg', 'rb').read()
    



    response = client.publish(
        PhoneNumber=phone_number,
        Message = "here is a picture: ",
        MessageAttributes = {
            'store' : {"DataType": "Binary", "BinaryValue": base64.b64encode(img)}
        }
    )
    print(response)
```

I am getting a success response and the text in `Message` argument but not the image:

```
{'MessageId': '2d435caa-bb24-5198-9bdc-04ecef05c0ef', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '5t97d18b-p15f-554b-b93f-819df53e64bc', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '5c97d98b-a15f-554b-bf3f-819df53e64bc', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '294', 'date': 'Fri, 30 Oct 2020 17:49:20 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Comment: I pasted the response in the question -- I am getting `text/xml` format in `content-type`.

Comment: What is the issue? `response` object does not contain the message, its normal.

Comment: The issue is that I am trying to send the .jpeg file image over text as well, but only the text is getting through. I meant the string in the `Message` attribute is arriving on my phone but not the image.

Comment: SNS is text only; it does not support sending images via SMS. A common pattern to work around this is to store the image in S3 and send the URL to the image which will preload on most phones.

Comment: Ok that would work as well. But in the boto3 1.16.8 documentation, it says: ```response = client.publish(
    TopicArn='string',
    TargetArn='string',
    PhoneNumber='string',
    Message='string',
    Subject='string',
    MessageStructure='string',
    MessageAttributes={
        'string': {
            'DataType': 'string',
            'StringValue': 'string',
            'BinaryValue': b'bytes'
        }
    },
    MessageDeduplicationId='string',
    MessageGroupId='string'
)``` supporting "Base64-encoded binary data object"